# Spring Cloud Config Server + BitBucket

Tags: spring, git, spring-cloud

I'm trying to get Spring Cloud's Config Server setup with a BitBucket private repository and haven't had any luck. No matter what configuration I use, I always seem to get a 404 returned when trying to load a configuration.

I've also tried setting breakpoints in `JGitEnvironmentRepository` but it never seems to get called outside of `afterPropertiesSet`. If I manually triggering the `findOne(application,profile,label)` while debugging, I get an error that `Branch name <null> not allowed`. If I specify "master" for `label` property, then I get the dreaded `Ref master cannot be resolved` error.

The app loads fine but no results. From all the documentation I've read, it seems like this should work out of the box. Any help would be appreciated.

**bootstrap.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  application:
    name: config-service
  cloud:
    bus.amqp.enabled: false
    config:
      enabled: false
      failFast: true
      server:
        prefix: /configs
        git :
          uri: https://bitbucket.org/[team]/[repo].git
          username: [user]
          password: [pass]
```

**Repo files**

```
- demo.app.yml
```

**Attempted URL**

http://localhost:8888/configs/demo.app

Answer (score 2):

1. you need to add a profile name to the url. The default profile is 'default'. http://localhost:8888/configs/demo.app/default
2. this only works with the 1.0.0.RELEASE version to me, but with the 1.0.1.RELEASE version I found a problem on Windows (there is a problem with the file separators so the config server didn't find the YAML files in the local cloned repository). Maybe this is the related issue: [Spring Cloud Config | Git Based | Not working on windows machine](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/164)

Comment: @David Welch, yup, proper url is `http://localhost:8888/configs/demo.app/default`.  I was able to get bitbucket private repos working without a problem.  The api is `/<appname>/<profile>` or `/<appname>/<profile>/<label>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have any issues, you can refer to the below client configuration. I have successfully configured the bitbucket repository.

```
Spring Boot Version: 1.4.1.RELEASE

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
bootstrap.yml

spring:
    application:
      name: client-config
    cloud:
      config:
        failFast: true
        label: master
        profile: default
        username: <username>
        password: <password>
        server:
          bootstrap: true
        uri: http://localhost:8888
```

Comment: Can you show server configuration also. this userName and password is for bitbucket & is these should be inside the client or config server.. also it will be help ful if you can show directory structure in bitbucket. I am able to get configuration from github but not from bitbucket